# How do I make my React Native module automatically add an entry to a project's Podfile after running react-native link?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I want to create a React Native module that can be installed using

```
npm install --save react-native-my-module
react-native link
cd ios && pod install
```

Using React Native 0.61.2 and a few required SDKs

---

1. Followed the instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup) to create a basic React Native module.
2. Installed the module using `npm install --s 'path to my-module'`
3. Ran `react-native link`
4. Installed the pod with `cd ios && pod install`

I saw my pod being successfully installed.

---

The default native module skeleton sets up a method called sampleMethod that I invoke using

```
var myModule = NativeModules.MyModule;
console.log(myModule.sampleMethod());
```

But I get the following error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sampleMethod' of undefined
```

---

To fix the error I have to manually link the module with `react-native link my-module` but then React Native complains

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:

- react-native-my-module (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-my-module")
```

What am I missing here? Do I have to manually link the module or is there a configuration file I can edit somewhere to avoid that?